# Laravel middleware logic doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a middleware that redirects users to a verification page if no data is found on the identification table but I keep getting the logic for the if statement wrong

I already tried the `$request->user()->identification->()has('user_id)` as my if statement

//From my **identification** middleware, I have this;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;

class Identification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (! $request->user()->identification()->verified) {

            return redirect('identification');

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I expect that this should return as true and proceed to the next page since i already have data on the Identifications table belonging to this user

but I get this error

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne :: $verified

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE) 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne :: $verified

Comment: Please post your Model code here (the relationship method).

Comment: `public function identification(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Identification');

    }`

Comment: `public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }`

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the problem is your if statement and it should be like this:
 `if (! $request->user()->identification->verified)`

Comment: Yup. `identification()` is an Eloquent query builder. `identification` is the query *result*. Common mistake people make in Laravel.

Comment: But what I am aiming to achieve is checking if the record exists in the identification table


`if (! $request->user()->exists('identification'))`

Comment: @KingKesh You should be able to just do `if($request->user()->identification) {}`.